# How to sort two colums in a view based on one column?

Tags: views, 8

I have two columns in table header and I have to sort them based on one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Sort Criteria?

For example sorting the results based on column Title:

[image: Sort Criteria]